# Problems with Queries in cloud code

Tags: javascript, php, parse-platform

Any ideas why this isn't working? It comes back with the success message but doesn't actually update anything.

I'm adding an FB user using Parse but since it doesn't have a func to add the username and email trying to do it this way. Any help much appreciated.

JS

```
Parse.Cloud.run("test", { objectId: "Q8XRUcL22N", name: "Rich", email: "rich@gmail.com"}, {
    success: function(results) {
        console.log(results);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

CLOUD CODE:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("test", function (request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var uid;
    var query = new Parse.Query("_User");

    query.count({
        success: function (results) {
            uid = parseInt(results);

        },
        error: function () {
            response.error("UID lookup failed");
        }
    });

    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    query.equalTo("objectId", request.params.objectId);

    query.first({
        success: function (object) {

            object.set("username", request.params.name);
            object.set("email", request.params.email);
            object.set("uid", uid);
            var acl = new Parse.ACL();
            acl.setPublicWriteAccess(false);
            acl.setPublicReadAccess(false);
            object.setACL(acl);
            object.save();
            response.success("Success Message");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            response.error("Error Message");
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `success()` or `error()` on the response halts whatever is underway at the time, including the `save()` on the user.

Also, it looks like you want to record in the user a count of users at the time the ACL is set.  Getting the count must also be serialized with the other operations.  (Also, please note that count is only good as an id "uid" to the extent the user count never goes down.  What's wrong with the parse objects's id as an id?).

Most of the parse functions return promises, and using them is the only way to not go nuts trying to nest callbacks. So...

```
Parse.Cloud.define("test", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var uid;
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.count().then(function(count) {
        uid = count;
        return query.get(request.params.objectId);
    }).then(function(object) {
        object.set("username", request.params.name);
        object.set("email", request.params.email);
        object.set("uid", uid);
        var acl = new Parse.ACL();
        acl.setPublicWriteAccess(false);
        acl.setPublicReadAccess(false);
        object.setACL(acl);
        return object.save();
    }).then(function (object) {
        response.success(object);
    },function(error) {
        response.error("Error Message");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Danh, That makes sense that success () / Error() will end the function. Also I suppose that the ID could be theirs I've just come from MySQL so still getting used to it. Thanks